# Using dotnetRDF library to query Large RDF file by SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

i want to query an Ontology which is defined in an RDF file using SPARQL and dotnetRDF library. The problem is that the file is large, so it's not very practical to load the entire file in memory. What should i do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use a triple store ...

Comment: instead of what?

Comment: ??? if in-memory is not working anymore, a proper triple store has to be used into which the data is loaded in advance.

Comment: Okay, i will try that. thank you so much

Comment: would you please suggest a native triple store supported by dotnetRDF ?

Comment: I am working on something similar, reading the Wikidata Dump. I am using dotnetrdf to parse triples and store them in a Lucene Index to store the information and be able to run queries. Maybe it will not be exactly what you need, but it might guide you: [github](https://github.com/gabrieldelaparra/SparQLforHumans)

Comment: any triple store should be supported as long as the SPARQL protocol is implemented. you should first check your requirements like size of the data, open source, inferencing needed, fulltext support needed, geo-spatial support needed, etc.

Comment: See the documentation on Triple Store integration - https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration and supported providers - https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Storage-Providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AKSW says in the comment, the best approach would be to load your RDF file into a triple store and then run your SPARQL queries against that. dotNetRDF ships with support for several triple stores as listed at https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Storage-Providers. However, all you really need is a triple store that supports the SPARQL protocol and then you will be able to run your queries from dotNetRDF code using the `SparqlRemoteEndpoint`class as described at https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Querying-With-SPARQL#remote-query.

As for which triple store to use, [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) with [Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/index.html) is probably a good open-source choice.